# Quiero agregarle campos a cada objeto que viene de una consulta mysql codeigniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Tengo la siguiente consulta que me trae de momento 2 rows que más adelante esa tabla se llenará más...

```
// Acá estamos en el modelo...
public function GetLocales() {
    $query  = 'SELECT loc.codigo_contable, emp.razon_social, loc.codigo, loc.nombre, evem.fecha_comprobacion, ';
    $query .= 'IF(evem.glosa="","NO APLICA", evem.glosa) AS glosa, evem.codigoevento ';
    $query .= 'FROM eltit_dte_manager.clientes_locales AS loc ';
    $query .= 'INNER JOIN eltit_dte_manager.clientes_dte AS emp ';
    $query .= 'ON (loc.codigo_contable = emp.codigo_contable) ';
    $query .= 'INNER JOIN eltit_auditoria.dte_eventos_empresas AS evem ';
    $query .= 'ON (loc.codigo = evem.local) ';
    $query .= 'WHERE loc.mostrar_monitor_acuse = "1" ';

    $rpta = $this->db->query($query);

    if ($rpta->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $rpta->result();
    } else {
        return "0";
    }
}
```

Esto lo capturo en el controlador que aquí es donde necesito agregarle más campos "clave => valor" y he intentado de varias maneras, 2 de ellas son los siguientes foreach

```
// Aquí estamos en el controlador...
public function getlocales() {
    $locales = $this->Auditoria->GetLocales();
    $arrColumnas = array('','','','','','','','','','','','','');
    $arrLocales = array();

    $i = 0;
    $local = new stdClass;

    foreach ($locales as $dato) {
        $arrLocales = array(
            $local[$i]->codigo_contable = $dato->codigo_contable,
            $local[$i]->razon_social = $dato->razon_social,
            $local[$i]->codigo = $dato->codigo,
            $local[$i]->nombre = $dato->nombre,
            $local[$i]->fecha_comprobacion = $dato->fecha_comprobacion,
            $local[$i]->codigo_evento = $dato->codigoevento,
            $local[$i]->col1 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col2 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col3 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col4 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col5 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col6 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col7 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col8 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col9 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col10 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col11 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col12 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col13 = "ROJO"
        );
        $i++;
    }
    /*
    foreach($locales as $dato) {
        $arrLocales = array(
            "codigo_contable" => $dato->codigo_contable,
            "razon_social" => $dato->razon_social,
            "codigo" => $dato->codigo,
            "nombre" => $dato->nombre,
            "fecha_comprobacion" => $dato->fecha_comprobacion,
            "codigo_evento" => $dato->codigoevento,
            "col1" => "ROJO",
            "col2" => "ROJO",
            "col3" => "ROJO",
            "col4" => "ROJO",
            "col5" => "ROJO",
            "col6" => "ROJO",
            "col7" => "ROJO",
            "col8" => "ROJO",
            "col9" => "ROJO",
            "col10" => "ROJO",
            "col11" => "ROJO",
            "col12" => "ROJO",
            "col13" => "ROJO"
        );
    }
    */
    $locales = $arrLocales;
    
    echo json_encode($locales);
}
```

Y mi problema es que de estas maneras sólo me devuelve un objeto que es el último que recorre el foreach... De qué manera podría guardar estos objetos en un array y retornarlo para recorrerlo en la llamada Ajax ?
Mi duda sólo es qué debo hacer en el controlador, lo de cómo mostrarlo con Ajax no me es difícil

Comment: El formato del sitio es de _preguntas y respuestas_. En lugar de editar tu pregunta explicando tu propia solución, _ponlo como respuesta_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que solo estás recorriendo el array pero no asignas en cada recorrido cada una de tus filas a un array acumulador.

Utiliza `array_push` para asignar el array temporal al acumulador y luego puedes imprimirlo con `echo`:

```
public function getlocales() {
    $locales = $this->Auditoria->GetLocales();
    
    $arrLocales = array();

    $i = 0;
    $local = new stdClass;

    foreach ($locales as $dato) {
        //se crea un array temporal en cada recorrido
        $nuevoArray = array(
            $local[$i]->codigo_contable = $dato->codigo_contable,
            $local[$i]->razon_social = $dato->razon_social,
            $local[$i]->codigo = $dato->codigo,
            $local[$i]->nombre = $dato->nombre,
            $local[$i]->fecha_comprobacion = $dato->fecha_comprobacion,
            $local[$i]->codigo_evento = $dato->codigoevento,
            $local[$i]->col1 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col2 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col3 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col4 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col5 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col6 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col7 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col8 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col9 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col10 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col11 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col12 = "ROJO",
            $local[$i]->col13 = "ROJO"
        );
        array_push($arrLocales, $nuevoArray); //se agrega el array temporal a un acumulador
        $i++;
    }

    $locales = $arrLocales;
    
    echo json_encode($locales);
}
```

Comment: Gracias Rafael por responder, lo pude resolver pero no de la manera en que me lo dijiste, sino que algo muy parecido porque me daba un error con tu ejemplo, edito la pregunta con la solución implementada

Answer (score 0):

Esto fue lo que hice para poder enviar el array con los objetos...

```
public function getlocales() {
    $locales = $this->Auditoria->GetLocales();
    $arrLocales = array();
    
    foreach($locales as $dato) {
        // Asigno lo extraido desde la bd a un array temporal y añado los campos que necesito
        $arrTemp = array(
            "codigo_contable" => $dato->codigo_contable,
            "razon_social" => $dato->razon_social,
            "codigo" => $dato->codigo,
            "nombre" => $dato->nombre,
            "fecha_comprobacion" => $dato->fecha_comprobacion,
            "codigo_evento" => $dato->codigoevento,
            "col1" => "ROJO",
            "col2" => "ROJO",
            "col3" => "ROJO",
            "col4" => "ROJO",
            "col5" => "ROJO",
            "col6" => "ROJO",
            "col7" => "ROJO",
            "col8" => "ROJO",
            "col9" => "ROJO",
            "col10" => "ROJO",
            "col11" => "ROJO",
            "col12" => "ROJO",
            "col13" => "ROJO"
        );
        // El array temporal lo convierto en un objeto
        $arrTemp = (object)$arrTemp;
        // Lo agrego el objeto al array $arrLocales...
        array_push($arrLocales, $arrTemp);
    }
    $locales = $arrLocales;
    echo json_encode($locales);
}
```